# Cannot find inux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, linux-kernel

I want install a virtual box on Kali linux and I get a error message : 
 ***This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel***

I try to install Linux-headers
I did a 
***"apt-get update"*** 
***apt-get install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)***

I got this message **it is unable to locate the package.**

If  this because the old kernel headers have been removed from the central package repository how can I install current haders 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 without doing upgrade

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this on Kali Linux? Before you say you are, please [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski 
thanks for your answer but i don't agree with this policy that says kali linux is for experts,

how do you excpect  to become an expert if you use tools for beginners?

   if you ask me to install ubuntu i do not like the sudo  and i have no time to waste time installing necessary scripts for pentesting on ubntue 

and  please stop telling pepole that kali linux it made just for experts at worst case in case of misfortune they reinstalls the operating system

Comment: I provide information and I won't stop doing this. It's up to you what you'll do with it. However, I don't know if I'd like to see your "how do you expect to become an expert if you use tools for beginners?" policy when you choose to learn axe juggling.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski
it's just an operating system it will not bite you , if you did something wrong reinstall them that all ,anyway  it's my opinion and you have yours .